# How to store og meta tag information?

Tags: php, html, mysql, metadata, meta-tags

I'm using the following PHP code to grab the `og:image` property from a webpage:

```
$site_html = file_get_contents($some_url);
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($site_html);
$meta_og_img = null;

foreach ($html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {
    if ($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image') { 
        $meta_og_img = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
}
```

I am expecting to need the `og:image` information on each page load, so would it be best (in terms of page load times, etc) to either (1) fetch the `og:image` from the external website every time the user loads the page or (2) fetch the `og:image` once and store it on my server?

Secondly, if I'm to store the `og:image` image on my server, how should I organize where it's located?

For example, if I need the `og:image` from the following webpage URL, how and where would I store the given `og:image` on my server:

```
Link: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/10/20/hong-kong-negotiations-go_n_6016982.html?utm_hp_ref=canada&ir=Canada
og:image: http://i.huffpost.com/gen/2187192/thumbs/o-UMBRELLA-COPS-facebook.jpg
```

Would I store the URL in a database table and give it a unique ID, such that the server directory to the `og:image` would then be something like:

```
/var/www/html/og_images/<ID>/image.jpg
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it better to store it or get it every time: It is definitely better to keep as much remote information stored locally as possible. The more remote calls necessary, the slower page load times. If you're concerned about having the most recent image, then there are several ways to asynchronously fetch content without it affecting the user experience.

As far as storage is concerned, there are several directions you can go with this. You need to determine how many images you will be storing and what is the space requirement. If you have enough disk space, then you certainly can store the images on the local hard drive, but then you need to consider that as traffic increases, there will be more requests for the images coming to the server.

A smarter solution is to look into using a solution like Amazon S3 and serve static files directly from their CDN, CloudFront. Then you won't be incurring extra traffic on your webserver just to deliver static files.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could probably store everything into your database.

   ```
   $url = 'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/10/20/hong-kong-negotiations-go_n_6016982.html?utm_hp_ref=canada&ir=Canada';    
   $ogImageUrl = 'http://i.huffpost.com/gen/2187192/thumbs/o-UMBRELLA-COPS-facebook.jpg';    
   $image = file_get_contents('http://i.huffpost.com/gen/2187192/thumbs/o-UMBRELLA-COPS-facebook.jpg');    

   $escaped_url = mysql_real_escape_string($url);
   $escaped_ogImageUrl = mysql_real_escape_string($ogImageUrl);

   $query = 'INSERT INTO `og_images` (`url`, `og_image_url`, `image`)
         VALUES ('.$escaped_url.', '.$escaped_ogImageUrl.', $image)";
   ```

I don't know if storing images into the db is a good idea. 
Boils down to the question: "to blob or not to blob"? See [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) for a pro / contra arguments.

Pro argument is: very easy SELECT query.

2. You could store just the links and a pointer to a cache folder.
3. You could store just the links and a pointer to an external CDN.

   - do you need fail-over access? [Amazon S3: when/why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731526/amazon-s3-when-why)

All these decisions depend on the use case and traffic expected.
If this is a low traffic site, storing to db might suffice
If this is a high traffic site, a CDN layer might be the better choice.

Comment: Yeah, the main problem with this is that if their website goes offline or they remove the image, I no longer have that image at my disposal.

Comment: I don't understand. The image is on stored on your server. The only problem with these approaches is, that you have to crawl the pages, to keep things in sync. It's basically a cache warming strategy.